# Exported animation does not loop keyframes when using cyclic (F-Modifier)

Tags: modifiers, export, keyframes, fcurves

I made an animation with keyframes ranging from frame 1 to frame 250. I select all the keyframes, press `SHIFT + E` and select `Make Cyclic (F-Modifier)`. I set the final range frame to 5000. The animation correctly loops from frame 1 to frame 5000. I export to FBX, and import it again. The animation doesn't loop anymore until frame 5000, it stops after the frame 250. Why? How can I make Blender repeat the keyframes until frame 5000 when exporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

right click on your object -> bake action, choose visual keying and choose the frame range you want to have. Then export.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what needed to be done. In my case, I had to select both Pose and Object.

Comment: glad you made it!